# Visual Studio 2013 - Excel Data to Label or Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have figures within an Excel workbook which add up each time numerical values are entered within tables. So if in the table I have 775 and 1045 then then one cell will show the total. I just want that one cell with the overall numerical figure to display in a label or textbox in Visual Studio. Will it also update automatically when the workbook is updated? As the workbook is updated everyday.

Answer (score 0):

'Open the excel document

```
    Process.Start("Excel", fileLocation)
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.workbooks.open(fileLocation)
    oSheet = oBook.worksheets(1)
```

'Pull data from Excel

```
    txtName.Text = oSheet.Range("C5").value
```

However, you would have to run this anytime you wanted the information, but still would pull all the data with just the click of a button vs doing it manually.